# Find out operators instead of variables in an equation?

Tags: algorithms

Is there a way to find out which operators satisfy an equation like this?

$$12 \_\_ 3\_\_  45\_\_  4 = 1769$$

Ans: $$12^3+45-4=1769$$

Comment: no. this looks like pure hit and trial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reduce SATISFIABILITY to this problem. Rather than dealing with two values (true or false), we have five values (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and exponentiation). So the problem you have described is NP-Complete.

Comment: Ah. I said it looks like hit and trial, you prove so. Good job. +1